# How do you modify sys.path in Google App Engine (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sys.path

I've tried adding the following line to my handler script (main.py), but it doesn't seem to work:

> sys.path.append('subdir')

`subdir` lives in the my root directory (i.e. the one containing `app.yaml`).

This doesn't seem to work, because when I try to import modules that live in `subdir`, my app explodes.

Comment: $10 says you had an errant `.pyc` file if the error "fixed itself".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1) Ensure you have a blank `__init__.py` file in `subdir`.

2) Use a full path; something like this:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'subdir'))
```

---

Edit:  providing more info to answer questions asked in a comment.

[As Nick Johnson demonstrates](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) you can place those three lines of code in a file called `fix_path.py`.  Then, in your `main.py` file, do this `import fix_path` before all other imports.  [Link to a tested application using this technique](http://bitbucket.org/abernier/yab/src/dc1fbe541d17/).

And, yes, the `__init__.py` file is required; per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> When importing the package, Python
>   searches through the directories on
>   sys.path looking for the package
>   subdirectory.
>
> The `__init__.py` files are required to
>   make Python treat the directories as
>   containing packages; this is done to
>   prevent directories with a common
>   name, such as string, from
>   unintentionally hiding valid modules
>   that occur later on the module search
>   path. In the simplest case,
>   `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization
>   code for the package or set the
>   `__all__` variable, described later.

Comment: I don't want to create a package named subdir. Isn't that what 1) will do? Also, where would I put the code you mentioned under 2)??

Comment: 2) is the answer I'm looking for. 1) As your quote from the docs explains, this makes subdir a package, which is NOT what I want.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why my original method of adding sys.path.append('subdir') to main.py (the only non-static handler in my app.yaml) didn't work. I just tried it again, but this time, no explosion :/

Comment: The `__init__.py` is **not** required when altering `sys.path`.  The path you are adding isn't a module itself, rather its contents are.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me inserting the new dirs as the first entries in sys.path.

path_changer.py:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libs'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'apps'))
```

app.py:

```
import path_changer
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

from flask import Flask
import settings

app = Flask('myapp')
app.config.from_object('settings')

from website import views as website_views

run_wsgi_app(app)
```