# Google App Engine Python: sys.path.append not working online

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this

```
import sys
sys.path.append('extra_dir')
import extra_module
```

It work perfectly under Windows XP App Engine SDK (offline)

But when deploy online, it give me `<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>`, what am I missing to deploy it online?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you modify sys.path in Google App Engine (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354166/how-do-you-modify-sys-path-in-google-app-engine-python)

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'extra_dir'))
```