# Google App Engine, Change which python version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, path, google-cloud-storage, sys.path

I'm trying to use the GCS client library with my app engine app and I ran into this -

"In order to use the client library in your app, put the `/src/cloudstorage` directory in your `sys.path` so Python can find it."

First, does this mean I need to move the directory into my `sys.path` OR does it need to add the `~/src/cloudstorage/` to my PATH environment variable?

Second, when I print `sys.version` and `sys.path` from the App Engine Interactive Console, I see a Python Version of 2.7.2, but when I print from my Terminal (on a Mac), I get the Python I want to use and installed via Homebrew - 2.7.5. The `sys.path` in the Console shows all App Engine paths and the default Python installation - `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`

On my terminal - `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`

I need help understanding how to change this.

** UPDATE **

Okay, I figured out part of this answer. "In order to use the client library in your app, put the `/src/cloudstorage` directory in your `sys.path` so Python can find it." means moving the actual directory to the App Engine project directory.

The second piece still remains - why is my Mac PATH environment variable not used in APP Engine. How can I change the default version of Python used by the App Engine (from 2.7.2 to 2.7.5)? This is not related to changing the version in the YAML file.

Comment: how do you run the devserver?

Comment: See here for moving to the project directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888110/google-app-engine-python-sys-path-append-not-working-online

Answer (score 1):

In GAE change the python path via Preferences settings, set Python Path to match your python 27 path.