# Using gcloud-python in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

I've got a bunch of little Raspberry Pis running some python code which saves directly to the Datastore (skips GAE) using the gcloud-python datastore package. This works great. I now want to present the data via web and mobile clients using Google App Engine. On my MacBook I installed GAE using the installer and gcloud via pip. I can write a simple python script and execute it directly from the terminal which is able to write and read from the datastore via gcloud - that also works just fine.

However, when I try to incorporate that same code into GAE it fails. Based on my research, I expect that it is a PATH issue but after several hours of various attempts I am unable to resolve this. Suggestions would be appreciated.

I believe this post is similar to my issue: [Google App Engine, Change which python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407249/google-app-engine-change-which-python-version)

Here are some pieces of information which may be relevant:

**Python version**

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Per the referenced Stack Overflow issue I set the preferences of GAE to have a Python Path of /usr/bin/python. I have tried it

**$PATH**

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/sheridangray/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

**os.path from Python interpreter**

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
```

**gcloud installation**

```
$ pip install --upgrade gcloud
Requirement already up-to-date: gcloud in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
...
```

**Python 2.7 references**

```
$ sudo find / -name python2.7
Password:
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/include/python2.7
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/python2.7
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/python2.7
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7
```

**Relevant Code**

```
from gcloud import datastore

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     dataset = datastore.get_dataset(dataset_id, email_address, private_key_file)
```

**GAE Log File**

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
--skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8000
Python command: /usr/bin/python
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:03,276 devappserver2.py:745] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:03,288 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49183
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:03,292 dispatcher.py:185] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:03,294 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:34,319 module.py:709] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:34,455 module.py:709] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 8348
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:44,359 module.py:387] Detected file changes:
  /Users/sheridangray/Projects/city-pulse-web/main.py
ERROR    2014-11-21 09:02:46,443 webapp2.py:1552] gcloud
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/city-pulse-web/main.py", line 63, in get
dataset = datastore.get_dataset(dataset_id, email_address, private_key_file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gcloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 103, in get_dataset
connection = get_connection(client_email, private_key_path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gcloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 65, in get_connection
    from gcloud.datastore.connection import Connection
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gcloud/datastore/connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gcloud import connection
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gcloud/connection.py", line 8, in <module>
class Connection(object):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gcloud/connection.py", line 24, in Connection
USER_AGENT = "gcloud-python/{0}".format(get_distribution('gcloud').version)
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 311, in get_distribution
if isinstance(dist,Requirement): dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 197, in get_provider
return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/Users/sheridangray/Projects/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: gcloud
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:46,456 module.py:709] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5010
INFO     2014-11-21 09:02:46,514 module.py:709] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run `gcloud-python` on App Engine, but it requires a
little extra work. Check out a skeleton [project](https://github.com/dhermes/test-gcloud-on-gae) I wrote
which gets this working.

The main bases to cover are:

### Getting the dependencies

In [`install_gcloud.sh`](https://github.com/dhermes/test-gcloud-on-gae/blob/8a850fb8b5676ca03e07c4f9dcfba5efb8c77b0a/install_gcloud.sh), `pip` is used to install `gcloud` and its
dependencies inside the application using

```
pip install --target="application/vendor/" gcloud
```

(As mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27064342/1068170), local installs don't get uploaded
to App Engine on deploy.)

### Modifying the dependencies

By `pip`-installing with `--target` set, `pkg_resources.get_distribution`
will work as expected (it failed in your stack trace).

In addition `pytz` by default has too many reads to work well on
App Engine, so [`gae-pytz`](https://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/) is used instead. As a result, some `pytz`
imports need to be modified.

In addition, to reduce a Compute Engine check overhead (network overhead),
the `oauth2client.client` module can be modified.

Both of these tweaks can be found in a single [commit](https://github.com/dhermes/test-gcloud-on-gae/commit/14bf5c5662a1093e9aeea9320b57cb88cfb1955f).

### Making Imports Work

The script above puts all dependencies in a directory called `vendor/` and
[`appengine_config.py`](https://github.com/dhermes/test-gcloud-on-gae/blob/8a850fb8b5676ca03e07c4f9dcfba5efb8c77b0a/application/appengine_config.py) adds this to the import path via
[Darth Vendor](https://github.com/jonparrott/Darth-Vendor):

```
import darth
darth.vendor('vendor')
```

In addition, since the `protobuf` dependency is also part of the
`google` package (just like all the App Engine imports, e.g.
`google.appengine.ext.ndb`) you need to modify the `__path__`
associated with that package:

```
import os
import google

curr_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
vendor_dir = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'vendor')
google.__path__.append(os.path.join(vendor_dir, 'google'))
```

### CAVEAT (as of January 22, 2015)

Be very aware that using `gcloud-python` within App Engine will be
3-5x slower than using the native App Engine libraries `db` or `ndb`.
This is because those use direct RPCs into the App Engine runtime while
`gcloud-python` will use HTTP outside of App Engine to talk to the Cloud
Datastore API.

---

**NOTE**: I updated this after the initial posting, which referenced
a previous [point](https://github.com/dhermes/test-gcloud-on-gae/commit/6b85e80d8edfc56e7f65b91898086b3f342a7c7b) in history.

Comment: Let me add that the `DistributionNotFound` error will still occur if you (redundantly) include some of the `google-cloud-python` dependencies in your `app.yaml`. Clear out the includes from `app.yaml` to fix.

Comment: FYI, as of at least CY2022 (perhaps earlier), [Darth Vendor](https://github.com/jonparrott/Darth-Vendor) is not required any more... if I'm reading [DarthVendor/README.md](https://github.com/theacodes/Darth-Vendor/README.md) correctly, use `from google.appengine.ext import vendor`

Answer (score 1):

GAE on your Mac can't access Python packages installed in the default place on your Mac.  You need to do this:

```
ln -s /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/.../gcloud /Users/sheridangray/Projects/city-pulse-web/gcloud
```

(need to replace ... with the relevant path info)

Comment: I tried adding a symbolic link like you said and ended up with the same error. That also got me thinking that when I do deploy the code the local package wouldn't be available which also would be problematic. So I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648256/uploading-python-third-party-libraries-with-google-app-engine. When I print out list(sys.modules.keys()) I can see that the module is actually being imported but I still get the DistributionNotFound error.

Comment: @SheridanGray did you ever figure this out?  If so, do you mind posting an answer?  Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using gcloud for writing directly to the Datastore and bypassing GAE and using NDB for when I was working in GAE.