# Where does `gcloud.datastore` persist its local dev state, and how do I clear it?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I am experimenting with [Google App Engine's flexible Python 3 environment and Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-datastore). When testing locally, this (generally) calls for running your app in something like Gunicorn and accessing the Datastore API from `gcloud.datastore`. For example:

```py
import gcloud.datastore as g_datastore
ds = g_datastore.Client(...)
entity = datastore.Entity(key=ds.key(...))
ds.put(entity)
```

When run locally (in dev mode), Entities' states are persisted between runs. I can't for the life of me figure out where they are stored or how to clear the dev datastore that is created after creating/accessing `gcloud.datastore.Client`. As far as I can tell, it does not use the same place that `ndb` uses when run via `dev_appserver.py`.

I've tried to figure it out with something like this (when running OS X):

```sh
$ touch foo
$ GCLOUD_PROJECT=... python .../main.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: ...
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2016 10:36:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
...
^C
$ sudo find /private/tmp /var/db /var/tmp ~/.config/gcloud ~/Library -newer foo
...
# nothing meaningful
```

I tried looking at the source code, and found [some unit test cleanup code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/blob/master/system_tests/clear_datastore.py) that: a) isn't distributed with `pip install gcloud`; and (more important for me) b) doesn't give any clue as to where that stuff is actually stored.

I've even tried this while Gunicorn was running:

```sh
$ sudo lsof | grep -Ei 'python'
# nothing meaningful
```

Where the foo does `gcloud.datastore` store its state between runs when run locally (in dev mode)?!

Comment: You might want to read this answer which helps in setting up gcloud in a very detailed way for appengine. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28095663/1059396

Comment: I don't think that helps me. `dev_appserver.py` is not compatible with the flexible Python environment (esp. Python 3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boy do I feel silly!  By default, `gcloud.datastore` connects to ... (wait for it) ... the Google Cloud Datastore. The real one. I don't know why I expected any different.

I didn't figure this out right away because my local `gcloud` configuration was already provisioned to use my account credentials, and I had the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment set when running my local instance. Whoops!  (No wonder I wasn't seeing any changes on local disk!)

So, if you *want* to have a "dev" Cloud Datastore running locally, you'll need to run the [Datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator). This is more complicated than running `dev_appserver.py` (which pretty much takes care of all this for you; see, e.g., [this workflow](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/) for how to infer values for your `index.yaml` file from your app's Datastore calls). If you don't supply the `--data-dir` option to the `start` command, the default local storage location is `~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/...`.

Rather than delete the question, I'm leaving it here as a warning/explanation to numbskulls like myself.

Comment: I don't think this is a silly question.
The official documentation is not very explicit about this, and it's no wonder developers feel confused.