# ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

For an application, I have to use Google Vision API.
I am able to use `from google.cloud import vision` and do image analysis in my computer.
But, when I deploy my app on developmental server I am getting error:

```
File "C:\MyApp\detect.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    __version__ = get_distribution('google-cloud-vision').version
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\setuptools-0.6c11\pkg_resources.py", line 311, in get_distribution
    if isinstance(dist,Requirement): dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\setuptools-0.6c11\pkg_resources.py", line 197, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\setuptools-0.6c11\pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\setuptools-0.6c11\pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: google-cloud-vision
```

When I create `appengine_config.py` file that contains:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages')
```

I am getting error:

```
File "C:\Users\MyApp\detect.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision.client import Client
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\client.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision._gax import _GAPICVisionAPI
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\_gax.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.gapic.vision.v1 import image_annotator_client
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\gapic\vision\v1\image_annotator_client.py", line 31, in <module>
    from google.gax import api_callable
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\gax\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 41, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

When I tried the hack mentioned in the link below:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1893 
https://github.com/googleapis/gax-python/issues/149 
https://gist.github.com/nilleb/419122f2f6f1228650dd2dccbd01c5af

I am getting error:

```
File "C:\Users\MyApp\detect.py", line 11, in <module>
    class DummyProcessing(ModuleType):
NameError: name 'ModuleType' is not defined
```

Then I followed the instruction here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library 
And used this command:

```
pip install -t lib google-cloud-vision==0.28.0
```

And updated `appengine_config.py` file:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

I am getting error:

```
File "C:\Users\MyApp\detect.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision.client import Client
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\client.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision._gax import _GAPICVisionAPI
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\_gax.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.gapic.vision.v1 import image_annotator_client
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\gapic\vision\v1\image_annotator_client.py", line 31, in <module>
    from google.gax import api_callable
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\gax\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 41, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

Then I followed the instruction here:
[Using gcloud-python in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057935/using-gcloud-python-in-gae/28095663#28095663)

And used this command:

```
pip install -t vendor google-cloud-vision==0.28.0
```

I copied `appengine_config.py` and `darth.py` files from here:
https://github.com/dhermes/test-gcloud-on-gae/tree/8a850fb8b5676ca03e07c4f9dcfba5efb8c77b0a/application

I am getting error:

```
File "C:\Users\MyApp\detect.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision.client import Client
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\client.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision._gax import _GAPICVisionAPI
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision\_gax.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.gapic.vision.v1 import image_annotator_client
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\gapic\vision\v1\image_annotator_client.py", line 31, in <module>
    from google.gax import api_callable
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\gax\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 41, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

I don’t know what to do next. I am completely stuck right now.

Comment: Have you tried the "dirty hack" given in the last link? It sounds that the root cause of the bugs is the same.

Comment: I tried it and updated my question. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The traceback indicates that the library is installed in your local python system (`C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision`) not in the app itself as it should be for a standard env GAE app.

From [Google Cloud Vision API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/vision/v1):

> **App Engine**
>
> Because the Python client libraries are not installed in the [App
>   Engine Python runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/), they must be [vendored into
>   your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) just like third-party libraries.

From [Copying a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library):

> To use a third-party library that is not on the list of built-in
>   libraries bundled with the runtime:
>
> - Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as `lib/`.
>
>   ```
>   mkdir lib
>   ```
> - Use pip (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous step. For
>     example:
>
>   ```
>   pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>   ```
>
>   ...

Follow the entire vendoring procedure and re-try.

But from the comment on [issue 149](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-python/issues/149) you referenced you *might* have to wait for that issue to be resolved:

> **@nilleb** grpc isn't yet supported on App Engine standard.

Comment: Shouldn't matter if you call your app's lib dir `lib` or `vendor` as long as you have the matching config in `appengine_config.py`. But unfortunately my suspicion is confirmed - the blocking problem is really that this version of the vision client library uses gax/multiprocessing, which isn't yet supported in the standard environment. The only thing that comes to mind would be to try an older version, before such support was added (if you can find one). Donno if it makes sense - if you need any capability/fix added since that version probably not.

Comment: I tried `pip install -t vendor google-cloud-vision==0.24.0`, but I am getting same error. Which version I should try?
One more thing, when I am using `appengine_config.py` why it is still looking for `from google.cloud import vision` in `C:\Anaconda2\lib\`?

Comment: Not sure which version (I didn't play with that lib yet) - try digging through those issues, maybe you can figure out in which version the gax/multiprocessing was added and pick the previous one. Or blindky try other versions :) II think you may still have `lib` in `appengine_config.py`, which won't match the `vendor` dir. I'd suggest going back to `lib` instead of `vendor` (you can just rename the dir) - it matches the official docs and can help reduce confusion.