# attempted relative import with no known parent package on Google AppEngine with Python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, python-3.7

Getting the following error:

> "/srv/server.py", line 12, in  from .routes.solver import route as solve ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Deploying the app to AppEngine Standard env, and my project looks like so:

```
---/
 |_app.yaml
 |_server.py
 |_routes
   |_solver.py
```

In `server` I do `from .routes.solver import route as solve` and get the above error in GCP, but not locally.

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/483616 and a few others. Tried with `__init__.py` at pretty much every level and every location. Then saw that it wasn't needed for python3, so removed. Pretty much unsure what to do now.

Comment: Tried this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354166/how-do-you-modify-sys-path-in-google-app-engine-python. Both /srv and /srv/routes were on the path before using import. Did it with append and insert(0

Comment: Added back `__init__.py` too, since the official v3 docs mention it.

Comment: Tried that one too :)

Answer (score 1):

Not optimistic that this is the answer but just to throw it into the pot, have you seen [Problem with Python relative paths when deploying to Google App Engine Flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56591614/364088) ?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that looks like the same issue, but also no answer there.